# How to create this type of window,as described in the attached picture with HTML,CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/7/41736826.png/

I am trying to create this type of window with HTML,CSS and Javascript .No Jquery Please. Thanx in advance.

Comment: It's called a modal window. Google it.

Comment: No *gimme the code* (choosy, in addition) questions Please :| Show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to do it using box shadows and border radiuses:

```
border-radius:10px;
box-shadow:0 0 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/8MY4f/1/